# Image displaying as a horizontal image rather than a vertical one

Tags: html

I am learning HTML and I'm practicing adding pictures to my website. I tried this with a vertical image I took off my phone and rather than displaying as the way the image actually is, it rotates it 90 degrees.

My only code for the image is:

> img src="img/download4.jpg" alt="vertical image"

I think it could be a problem with my phone (Pixel 3a), but why is the website output displaying it as a horizontal image rather than a vertical one? I downloaded a random wallpaper off the internet and that seemed to work, so why doesn't mine?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try attaching the image to this post so that we can see it

Comment: Is it displayed correctly when opening your html on desktop?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jENRjp9 that's the image i was using as a test

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your style:

```
img {
    image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

and open it in firefox. If it shows how it supposed to it is due chrome issue to read EXIF data from image. There isn't much you can do about it without tampering with javascript.